# How to tackle log(0) numerically?

Tags: c++, matrix, precision

I am working with an Idempotent matrix, whose eigenvalues are either nearly `0` or `1`. The function i am interested in is

```
-e(i)*log(e(i)) - (1-e(i))*log(1-e(i))
```

where `e(i)` are the ith eigenvalues of the matrix.
When the eigenvalues is exactly `0`, then the first term exploits, and vice versa.

Comment: I believe you'll have to evaluate it as a special case, i.e. `if (x == 0.f) return 0.f; else return x * log(x);`

Comment: What do you want the answer to be mathematically?  That equation isn't defined at either `0` or `1`.  Do you want the answer to be `0`?  How about at `0.0000000001` or at `0.999999999`?  I may be wrong, but those aren't removable singularities.

Comment: using long double, i am able to remove the singularities near '0'. (1st term is OK so far). In the second term i have problem. I am getting exactly 1.0, means log(0).  Yes. i am looking for '0.9999999999999'

Comment: The limes of your expression is just 0 for e(i) = 0 and 1. See application of [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470952/limit-of-x-log-x-as-x-tends-to-0) for the "risky" part, and the other part is trivially 0 at the same time because of log(1).

Comment: I was trying to implement your **answer** in my code. (answer has been removed)@....

Comment: @NAK Sorry for that, I thought I had misunderstood your question, was going to look for another answer, and got interrupted. Can you clarify what output you expect for the inputs you find problematic? Is it only exactly 0 and 1, or is it their neighborhood, in which case what margin of error do you expect?

Comment: Thank you @Nelfeal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to work around a call to `log(0)`.

You can break your expression in two subexpressions with special cases:

```
auto A = e(i) == 0 ? 0 : -e(i)*log(e(i));
auto B = e(i) == 1 ? 0 : (1-e(i))*log(1-e(i));
return A - B;
```

You can handle both special cases first:

```
if (e(i) == 0 || e(i) == 1) {
    return 0;
}
return -e(i)*log(e(i)) - (1-e(i))*log(1-e(i))
```

You can define your own special `log`:

```
auto logOrZero = [](double f) -> double {
    return f == 0 ? 0 : log(f);
};
return -e(i)*logOrZero(e(i)) - (1-e(i))*logOrZero(1-e(i));
```

And so on.

In any case, you should not only be careful with passing zero to `log`, but also with passing values close to zero, because of precision issues.

Comment: Why would `0` be a reasonable answer for what `x log x` should be represented as at `x==0`?  Or for `log x` at `x==0`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The limit of `x log x` when `x` tends to `0` is `0`. In some cases (like in this one), you can just say that `0 log 0 = 0`, as a continuation of some function. As for the value of `log x` at `x = 0`, well I haven't said it was `0`. But `logOrZero(0) = 0`.

Comment: Instead of `log(1-e(i))`, I suggest to use [`std::log1p(-e(i))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p). This is much more accurate near 0. Near 1 the accuracy is no problem (only the singularity at exactly 1).